# Ant: Find the path of a file in a directory

Tags: file, ant, path, find

I want to find the path of a file in a directory (similar to unix 'find' command or the 'which' command, but I need it to work platform-independent) and save it as a property.

Tried to use the `whichresource` ant task, but it doesn't do the trick (I think it's only good for looking inside jar files).

I would prefer if it would be pure ant and not to write my own task or use a 3rd-party extension.

Notice that there might be several instances of a file by that name in the path - I want it to only return the first instance (or at least I want to be able to choose only one).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [`first`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#first) resource selector.  For example to find a file called `a.jar` somewhere under directory `jars`:

```
<first id="first">
    <fileset dir="jars" includes="**/a.jar" />
</first>
<echo message="${toString:first}" />
```

If there are no matching files nothing will be echoed, otherwise you'll get the path to the first match.

Comment: Awesome! That works great! Could you explain what it the `toString:` thingie?

Comment: It's just a way to 'stringify' an Ant type.  See http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#toString

Comment: Tried three other techniques including `resourcecount`, `condition`, `available` until landing on this.  This was the one that worked.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example which selects the first matching file. The logic is as follows:

- find all matches using a [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).
- using [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html), store the result in a property, separating each matching file with line separator.
- use a [head filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#headfilter) to match the first matching file.

The functionality is encapsulated in a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) for reusability.

```
<project default="test">

  <target name="test">
    <find dir="test" name="*" property="match.1"/>
    <echo message="found: ${match.1}"/>
    <find dir="test" name="*.html" property="match.2"/>
    <echo message="found: ${match.2}"/>
  </target>

  <macrodef name="find">
    <attribute name="dir"/>
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="property"/>
    <sequential>
      <pathconvert property="@{property}.matches" pathsep="${line.separator}">
        <fileset dir="@{dir}">
          <include name="@{name}"/>
        </fileset>
      </pathconvert>
      <loadresource property="@{property}">
        <string value="${@{property}.matches}"/>
        <filterchain>
          <headfilter lines="1"/>
        </filterchain>
      </loadresource>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a macro based on martin-clayton's answer.

sample project with macro and a property file that is read from the found file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="test properties file read" default="info">

<macrodef name="searchfile">
    <attribute name="file" />
    <attribute name="path" default="custom,." />
    <attribute name="name" />
    <sequential>
        <first id="@{name}">
            <multirootfileset basedirs="@{path}" includes="@{file}" erroronmissingdir="false" />
        </first>
        <property name="@{name}" value="${toString:@{name}}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<searchfile name="custom.properties.file" file="config.properties" />
<property file="${custom.properties.file}" />

<target name="info" >
    <echo>
origin ${config.origin}
</echo>

</target>
```